# Splitting text into n-grams and analyzing statistics on them

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, natural-language-processing

I have made the algorithm that split text into n-grams (collocations) and it counts probabilities and other statistics of this collocations. When file is more then 50 megabytes it takes long time to count maybe some one will help to improve it.

```
import math
import re
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
from datetime import datetime


def tokenize(input_file, encoding):
    lst =[]
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
        for sent in f:
            sent = sent.lower()
            sent = re.sub("[A-z0-9\'\"`\|\/\+\#\,\)\(\?\!\B\-\:\=\;\.\«\»\—\@]", '', sent)
            sent = re.findall('\w+', sent)
            for word in sent:
            lst.append(word)
    return lst


def ngrams_split(lst, n):
    counts = dict()
    grams = [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]
    for gram in grams:
        if gram not in counts:
            counts[gram] = 1
        else:
            counts[gram] += 1
    return counts


def list_add(counts):
    ngrams = []
    for key, val in counts.items():
        ngrams.append((val, key))
    return ngrams


def gram_add(lst, n):
    ng = []
    grams = [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]
    for gram in grams:
        ng.append(gram)
    return ng


def two_gram_count(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    output_file = []
    lst = tokenize(input_file, encoding) #tokenize
    n_words = len(lst)
    counts = ngrams_split(lst, n) #spliting into ngrams
    ngrams = list_add(counts)  #ading ngrmas to list
    for key, val in ngrams:
        if int(key) >= n_filter:
            ngram_freq = math.log(key/n_words)
            num = key*n_words
            f1 = lst.count(val.split()[0])
            f2 = lst.count(val.split()[1])
            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(f1*f2), 10), 2)
            ngram_prob = math.log(key/f1, 10)
            output_file.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, key, val))
    return output_file


def three_gram_count(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    output_file = []
    lst = tokenize(input_file, encoding) #tokenize
    n_words = len(lst)
    counts = ngrams_split(lst, n) #spliting into ngrams
    ngrams = list_add(counts)  #ading ngrmas to list
    ng = gram_add(lst, 2)
    for key, val in ngrams:
        if int(key) >= n_filter:
            ngram_freq = math.log(key/n_words, 10)
            num = key*n_words
            c2gram = ng.count(val.split()[0] + " " + val.split()[1])
            f1 = lst.count(val.split()[0])
            f2 = lst.count(val.split()[1])
            f3 = lst.count(val.split()[2])
            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(f1*f2*f3), 10), 2)
            ngram_prob = math.log(key/c2gram, 10)
            output_file.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, key, val))
    return output_file


def four_grams_count(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    output_file = []
    lst = tokenize(input_file, encoding) #tokenize
    n_words = len(lst)
    counts = ngrams_split(lst, n) #spliting into ngrams
    ngrams = list_add(counts)  #ading ngrmas to list
    ng2 = gram_add(lst, 2)
    for key, val in ngrams:
        if int(key) >= n_filter:
            ngram_freq = math.log(key/n_words, 10)
            num = key*n_words
            c1gram = ng2.count(val.split()[0] + " " + val.split()[1])
            c2gram = ng2.count(val.split()[1] + " " + val.split()[2])
            c3gram = ng2.count(val.split()[2] + " " + val.split()[3])
            f1 = lst.count(val.split()[0])
            f2 = lst.count(val.split()[1])
            f3 = lst.count(val.split()[2])
            f4 = lst.count(val.split()[3])
            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(f1*f2*f3*f4), 10), 2)
            prob1 = c1gram/f1
            prob2 = c2gram/f2
            prob3 = c3gram/f3
            ngram_prob = math.log(prob1, 10) + math.log(prob2, 10) +    math.log(prob3, 10)
           output_file.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, key, val))
    return output_file


def n_grams_stat(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    output_file = []
    if n == 2:
        for i in two_gram_count(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
            output_file.append(i)
    elif n == 3:
        for i in three_gram_count(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
            output_file.append(i)
    elif n == 4:
        for i in four_grams_count(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
            output_file.append(i)
    return output_file

start_time = datetime.now()
for a, b, c, d, e in n_grams_stat("/home/yan/PycharmProjects/vk/piidsluhano/men_pidsluhano.txt",'utf-8', n_filter=3, n=4):
    print(a, b, c, d, e)
    with open("/home/yan/PycharmProjects/vk/piidsluhano/men_4grams", 'dwwaa') as f:
        f.write(str(a)  +", "+ str(b) + ', '+ str(c) + ", " + str(d) + ", " + str(e) + '\n ')
end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Output: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jebMM6gZUMV0Ig6SPcveVYvccB6W9WBr_Yk8Zi2J72I/edit?usp=sharing

f - frequency, m -  mi shows how strong collocation is, p -probability, n - number of times, t - text 
output is in csv formst

Comment: Something like this might benefit a lot from just seeing how to actually *use* this code. Could you edit it to include an example?

Comment: You mean show the output of it?

Comment: Now you can see the output.

Comment: If you want you can try some texts, but you need to change this line re.sub("[A-z0-9\'\"`\|\/\+\#\,\)\(\?\!\B\-\:\=\;\.\«\»\—\@] because it takes a all Latin letters away.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReeview.SE. Your indentation seems to be somewhat broken.

Comment: Fixed it by adding link to my output.

Comment: @Yan: Just so that you know, I've added comments since you've accepted my answer so don't forget to have a look ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Code organisation**

Your code seems to be splitted into small-ish functions which is good. However, there is something that could easily be improved : you could move your code actually doing something (by opposition to merely define things) behind an [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

**User interface**

Your code contains hardcoded file paths. Obviously, this doesn't work on my machine without changing the code. The right way to do this is probably to use command-line arguments to be able to provide the path for the input file and for the output file. Alternatively, you could get rid of input and/or output file, just read from standard input and write in standard output and assume that the user knows enough about redirection to use your script.

**Do not repeat yourself**

Your code contains a lot of duplicated code which makes it hard to read and/or to maintain.

In your code, it may also make it less efficient than it could be because one may read and tokenize the file multiple times instead of only once.

For instance, we could imagine providing the list of tokens to the `xxx_grams_count` functions instead of filename and encoding. This could make things more straightforward but also easier to test.

Most of your functions do many things and do not respect the [Single Responsability Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

**Variable names**

Your variables names are in general not very descriptive. `lst` for a list of tokens is not good especially because you handle multiple other lists, `tokens` seems to be a better idea.

Also `output_file` for a list of frequencies is a terrible name : it is not even slightly related to file (except for the fact that the value returned might eventually be written in a file). `output_tuples` or `output_freq` or `ngram_count` might be slightly less confusing. You could probably find an even better name as you know more about the code than I do.

**Comments**

It is a good thing to have comments in your code but if the comments is just stating the obvious, it doesn't add any value while adding some noise.

For instance, this comment `lst = tokenize(input_file, encoding) #tokenize` doesn't add anything.

Also, it may be a good idea to add [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your function describing their input/output/behavior.

**Useless list manipulation**

You are performing many useless list manipulations.

In:

```
def gram_add(lst, n):
    ng = []
    grams = [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]
    for gram in grams:
        ng.append(gram)
    return ng
```

you are creating a new list, iterating over each item of that list to add it to an other list that you can return.

This could just be:

```
def gram_add(lst, n):
    return [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]
```

Pretty similarly, in :

```
def n_grams_stat(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    ngram_count = []
    tokens = tokenize(input_file, encoding)
    if n == 2:
        for i in two_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
            ngram_count.append(i)
    elif n == 3:
        for i in three_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
            ngram_count.append(i)
    elif n == 4:
        for i in four_grams_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
            ngram_count.append(i)
    return ngram_count
```

you are getting a list, iterating  over each item of that list to add it to an other list that you can return.

This could be written:

```
def n_grams_stat(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    tokens = tokenize(input_file, encoding)
    if n == 2:
        return two_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
    elif n == 3:
        return three_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
    elif n == 4:
        return four_grams_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
    return []
```

**List comprehension**

You seem to be aware of the existence of list comprehension but you haven't used them in a few places where it could be quite useful. For instance :

```
def list_add(counts):
    ngrams = []
    for key, val in counts.items():
        ngrams.append((val, key))
    return ngrams
```

could just be :

```
def list_add(counts):
    return [(val, key) for key, val in counts.items()]
```

also this still has 3 problems: the name of the function seems pretty bad (we don't "add" anything to any list) and the name of the parameter seems just as bad (`counts` suggest a list of number, not a dictionnary; maybe `dict_` would be a better name), the fact that this function can be simplified more.

I'll explain the third point which will make the 2 first points irrelevant. What you are actually doing in the function is consuming a list (or a view depending on the Python version but it doesn't matter for you) of (key, val) pairs and returning a list of (val, key) pairs but at the end of the day, you don't really care about the order, you could just swap your variable names when you iterate on the result.

Thus, changing : `for key, val in ngrams:` for `for val, key in ngrams:`, you could write :

```
def list_add(dict_):
    return dict_.items()
```

which makes the function useless.

**Using the correct data structure**

There are 2 things that could be improved in the `ngrams_split` function:

- it splits **and** it counts
- the counting part could be improved using the correct data structure. You'll see that [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) handle this task pretty well.

We can rewrite `ngrams_split` so that it only splits and use Counter to count its return:

```
def ngrams_split(lst, n):
    return [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]
```

That you use like this :

```
for val, key in Counter(ngrams_split(tokens, n)).items():
```

Then you can see that you have 2 pretty similar functions:

```
def ngrams_split(lst, n):
    return [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]


def gram_add(lst, n):
    return [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]
```

So you can remove `gram_add`.

**Variable names again**

Now, in all the places where `key` and `val` are used, it would be more precise to use `count` and `ngram`.

**Useless operations again**

Now that we have : `if int(count) >= n_filter`, it is more obvious that we are probably performing some conversion of an int to an int which is pointless.

**Useless repeated operations**

You are calling `ngram.split()` many times even when you know that `ngram` hasn't changed in the meantime. It would be clearer and more efficient to do this only once.

I still have things to say (about duplicated code mostly) but in the meantime, here is my current version of the code :

```
import math
import re
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
from datetime import datetime
from collections import Counter

def tokenize(input_file, encoding):
    lst =[]
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
        for sent in f:
            sent = sent.lower()
            # Commented for personal reasons : sent = re.sub("[A-z0-9\'\"`\|\/\+\#\,\)\(\?\!\B\-\:\=\;\.\Â«\Â»\--\@]", '', sent)
            sent = re.findall('\w+', sent)
            for word in sent:
                lst.append(word)
    return lst


def ngrams_split(lst, n):
    return [' '.join(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]


def two_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
    ngram_count = []
    n_words = len(tokens)
    for ngram, count in Counter(ngrams_split(tokens, n)).items():
        if count >= n_filter:
            splitted_ngram = ngram.split()
            ngram_freq = math.log(count/n_words)
            num = count*n_words
            f1 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[0])
            f2 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[1])
            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(f1*f2), 10), 2)
            ngram_prob = math.log(count/f1, 10)
            ngram_count.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, count, ngram))
    return ngram_count


def three_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
    ngram_count = []
    n_words = len(tokens)
    ng = ngrams_split(tokens, 2)
    for ngram, count in Counter(ngrams_split(tokens, n)).items():
        if count >= n_filter:
            splitted_ngram = ngram.split()
            ngram_freq = math.log(count/n_words, 10)
            num = count*n_words
            c2gram = ng.count(splitted_ngram[0] + " " + splitted_ngram[1])
            f1 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[0])
            f2 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[1])
            f3 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[2])
            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(f1*f2*f3), 10), 2)
            ngram_prob = math.log(count/c2gram, 10)
            ngram_count.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, count, ngram))
    return ngram_count


def four_grams_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
    ngram_count = []
    n_words = len(tokens)
    ng2 = ngrams_split(tokens, 2)
    for ngram, count in Counter(ngrams_split(tokens, n)).items():
        if count >= n_filter:
            splitted_ngram = ngram.split()
            ngram_freq = math.log(count/n_words, 10)
            num = count*n_words
            c1gram = ng2.count(splitted_ngram[0] + " " + splitted_ngram[1])
            c2gram = ng2.count(splitted_ngram[1] + " " + splitted_ngram[2])
            c3gram = ng2.count(splitted_ngram[2] + " " + splitted_ngram[3])
            f1 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[0])
            f2 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[1])
            f3 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[2])
            f4 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[3])
            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(f1*f2*f3*f4), 10), 2)
            prob1 = c1gram/f1
            prob2 = c2gram/f2
            prob3 = c3gram/f3
            ngram_prob = math.log(prob1, 10) + math.log(prob2, 10) +    math.log(prob3, 10)
            ngram_count.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, count, ngram))
    return ngram_count


def n_grams_stat(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    tokens = tokenize(input_file, encoding)
    if n == 2:
        return two_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
    elif n == 3:
        return three_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
    elif n == 4:
        return four_grams_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
    return []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = datetime.now()
    s = n_grams_stat("/home/josay/Geekage/review/ngram2.py",'utf-8', n_filter=3, n=4)
    for a, b, c, d, e in s:
        print(a, b, c, d, e)
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Edit: More comment :-)

**Useless imports**

Do I have to say more about this ?

Comment: i will check it out as soon as possible, And will see how faster it is going to work!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yan/PycharmProjects/nltk/n.py", line 97, in <module>
    s = n_grams_stat("/home/yan/woman_final.txt", encoding = "utf-8",  n_filter=1, n=2)
  File "/home/yan/PycharmProjects/nltk/n.py", line 87, in n_grams_stat
    return two_gram_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
  File "/home/yan/PycharmProjects/nltk/n.py", line 33, in two_gram_count
    f2 = tokens.count(splitted_ngram[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: gave error above.

Comment: Pretty weird. Seems to work for me. In any case, the point of my code review was more the ideas I've used than the resulting code. I think I've detailled the steps well enough so that you can do the same think from your code and see when it starts going wrong. I'd be curious to see which change causes the failure.

Comment: sure will inform you!

Comment: Great, thanks! Once you've solved the issue, don't forget to look at Jared Goguen's answer as it will help you to improve your code further than what I have done.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest improvement you could make is to generalize the two-gram, three-gram, and four-gram functions, into a single n-gram function. This can be done with using lists instead of manually assigning `c1gram`, `c2gram`, and so on.

```
def n_grams_count(tokens, n_filter, n):
    ngram_count = []
    word_count = len(tokens)
    ng2 = ngrams_split(tokens, 2)
    for ngram, count in Counter(ngrams_split(tokens, n)).items():
        if count >= n_filter:
            split = ngram.split()
            ngram_freq = math.log(count/word_count, 10)
            num = count*word_count

            cgrams = [ng2.count(split[i] + ' ' + split[i+1]) for i in range(n-1)]
            freqs = [tokens.count(word) for word in split]
            product = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, freqs)

            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(product), 10), 2)

            probs = [cgram/freq for cgram, freq in zip(cgrams, freqs)]
            ngram_prob = sum(math.log(prob, 10) for prob in probs)
            ngram_count.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, count, ngram))

    return ngram_count
```

I don't really understand what this function is doing, but it seems messy and could likely be improved.

Then your `n_grams_stat` function can be greatly simplified.

```
def n_grams_stat(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    tokens = tokenize(input_file, encoding)
    return n_grams_count(tokens, n_filter, n)
```

With this one change, you've gotten rid of half of your code and now can work with five-grams, six-grams, and so on.

Making some small other changes, many of which are noted above, cleans up the code pretty well.

```
import math, re, csv

from itertools import zip_longest
from datetime import datetime
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce

def tokenize(input_file, encoding):
    tokens = []
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
        for line in f:
            words = re.findall('\w+', line.lower())
            tokens.extend(words)
    return tokens


def chunk_list(lst, n):
    return [tuple(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n)]


def count_ngrams(tokens, n_filter, n):
    ngram_counts = []
    word_count = len(tokens)
    two_grams = chunk_list(tokens, 2)

    for ngram, count in Counter(chunk_list(tokens, n)).items():
        if count >= n_filter:
            ngram_freq = math.log(count/word_count, 10)
            num = count*word_count

            cgrams = [two_grams.count((ngram[i], ngram[i+1])) for i in range(n-1)]
            freqs = [tokens.count(word) for word in ngram]
            product = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, freqs)

            mi = math.pow(math.log(num/(product), 10), 2)

            probs = [cgram/freq for cgram, freq in zip(cgrams, freqs)]
            ngram_prob = sum(math.log(prob, 10) for prob in probs)
            ngram_counts.append((ngram_freq, mi, ngram_prob, count, ngram))

    return ngram_counts


def ngram_stats(input_file, encoding, n_filter, n):
    tokens = tokenize(input_file, encoding)
    return count_ngrams(tokens, n_filter, n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.now()
    s = ngram_stats('/home/josay/Geekage/review/ngram2.py','utf-8', n_filter=3, n=4)
    for tup in s:
        print(*tup)
    print('Duration: {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time))
```

Comment: Excellent answer handling the part of the review I had no time to perform/test. Your final code shows very interesting points that probably deserve to be explained : you got rid of the join/split operations,  you used `extend` instead of multiple `append`

Comment: Did you check if your code working because I've found two mistakes there?

Comment: @Yan I have not (mainly because I don't have test data). Hopefully, the mistakes are minimal enough that you are able to troubleshoot them yourself, but let me know what I need to correct, or if there is anything that just doesn't work. A good amount of renaming was done, which I'd assume is the issue.

Comment: for test data you can use any text file

Comment: File "/home/yan/PycharmProjects/nltk/n.py", line 26, in count_ngrams
    for ngram, count in Counter(chunk_list(tokens, n)).items():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 475, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 562, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list

Comment: it gives error above

Comment: And want to ask about this function reduce()? it should be imported?

Comment: If you're using Python 3, yes. `from functools import reduce`

Comment: yes, have already done it!

Comment: @Yan Okay, I've tested it and it works now. The issue was passing lists to `Counter` instead of tuples. Explicitly casting these in the `chunk_list` function resolved the issue. You didn't run into this in your original code because strings are hashable (it might be interesting to look up what hashable and immutable mean in Python).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37756/discussion-between-yan-and-jared-goguen).